# jQuery appending back to parent doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html

I have a script that strips a long unordered dropdown menu list into groups of 5, and appends them, with a parent `ul` back into their original li. This is the html at present.

```
<li class="dropdown menuB">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Drobdown B<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu row-fluid">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 12</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

jQuery(function(){
    var $bigList = jQuery('.menuB .dropdown-menu'), group;
    while((group = $bigList.find('li:lt(5)').remove()).length){
        var $ul = jQuery('<ul/>'),
        $eachLi = jQuery('<li/>', {class: ( 'span' + spanSize )});          
        $ul.append(group);
        $eachLi.append($ul);
        jQuery(".dropdown-menu").append($eachLi);
    }
});
```

If i append the new list anywhere else in the html, i.e. the body, a different `li` it works just fine, however when i append it back to the lists parent `ul` it crashes my browser, in every browser i have tried. Why am i not able to reappend to the original parent?

Comment: Why don't you use `.wrapAll` instead of all this removing and appending?

Comment: thats a different variable i forgot to take out that just adds a number to the class.

Comment: The reason it's crashing is because your `append` calls are backwards. They should be `appendTo`.

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward It's assigned in the `while` statement.

Comment: @Barmar thank you I messed that!

Comment: @Barmar i have the same outcome with append or appendTo, i was going to replicate the issue in jsfiddle but dont want to crash everyones browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrapping range of children elements in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406109/wrapping-range-of-children-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: they're different issues, the issue that question has is the bit i have sorted, saw that one earlier.